# script to connect servers and run some commands on amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, fish, locust

I want to write a fish script to run Locust on the amazon servers. I wrote the code as below, the problem is that when the shell connects to first server it cant send the other commands there.

Any helps, recommedationa are appreciated.

```
set labs 'ubuntu@compute1.amazonaws.com' 'ubuntu@compute2.amazonaws.com' 'ubuntu@compute3.amazonaws.com' 'ubuntu@compute4.amazonaws.com' 
set key /Users/mesutgunes/Desktop/project-key.pem

for lab in $labs
    ssh -i $key $lab 
    cd /path/to/project/
    screen
    locust -f file.py --master
    exit
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the commands you want to run as the final argument to the ssh command.

```
for lab in $labs
    ssh -i $key $lab screen locust -f /path/to/project/file.py --master
end
```

In this case that will work fine I think. Be careful when the remote command is more complex, especially if it contains quoted strings, as you can end up with a right dog's dinner of nested quotes!  If that happens, you're usually best to scp a script across, then run it using ssh.

Comment: thank you it works. I have receiving two message: `Must be connected to a terminal.` and `bash: =: command not found`. I also wonder normally I must pres `enter` key to activate `screen`, how do I handle it?

Comment: Change the command to:
    `command='cd /path/to/project/; screen locust -f file.py --master'`
That runs screen with that single command.  Could shorten even further to:
    `command='screen locust -f /path/to/project/file.py --master'`

Comment: Actually once you've done that, may as well inline the command - I'll update my answer